# Using Netbeans Visual Library in Javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to use the Net beans Visual Library in `Javafx` and I am referring to example here https://platform.netbeans.org/graph/examples.html.

I am particularly using the DemoGraphscene.java in the javaone.demo4 package. While I am using am using the example in my javafx project, I am not sure how to display the graph.

Here is what I have written in my controller class:

```
public class GraphicalViewController implements Initializable {

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */

    @FXML
    private Pane pane1;

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

         // TODO

       GraphScene scene = new DemoGraphScene ();

        String helloNodeID = "Hello";
        String worldNodeID = "World";
        String edge = "edge";

        Widget hello = scene.addNode (helloNodeID);
        Widget world = scene.addNode (worldNodeID);

        scene.addEdge (edge);

        scene.setEdgeSource(edge, helloNodeID);
        scene.setEdgeTarget(edge, worldNodeID);

        hello.setPreferredLocation (new Point (100, 100));
        world.setPreferredLocation (new Point (400, 200));

        pane1.getChildren().add(scene.getView());      

    }    

}
```

So I have  (argument mismatch; JComponent cannot be converted to Node) in the line `pane1.getChildren().add(scene.getView());`

How do I come about this problem?

I did this:

```
SwingNode swingScene = new SwingNode(); 
SwingNode swingScene1 = new SwingNode(); 
swingScene.setContent(new JButton("Click me!")); 
swingScene1.setContent(scene.getView()); 
pane1.getChildren().add(swingScene1);
```

When I do `pane1.getChildren().add(swingScene1)`, I see nothing is displayed, but `pane1.getChildren().add(swingScene)` does show the button.

Comment: Check your imports, all of them should be `javafx` specific.

Comment: import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import org.netbeans.api.visual.widget.Widget;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import org.netbeans.api.visual.graph.GraphScene;
import org.netbeans.api.visual.graph.layout.GridGraphLayout;
import org.netbeans.api.visual.layout.LayoutFactory;
import org.netbeans.api.visual.layout.SceneLayout;
I have import java.awt.Point for creating a point, how do I replace  hello.setPreferredLocation (new Point (100, 100)); ?

Comment: non-JavaFX imports are expected and OK in this scenario - just be careful how you use the imported APIs.  You probably want to study [JavaFX - Swing Interoperability](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/embed-swing.htm) in a bit of detail to understand what you need to do.

Comment: Please don't place a whole lot of import statements in a comment, instead edit the original question and add extra material in there as needed.  Also please try not to ask new questions in comments, instead ask new questions in new questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use a SwingNode**

The NetBeans Visual Library is Swing based.  If you want to use it in JavaFX, you need to [wrap the Swing component in a JavaFX node](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html).

```
@FXML Pane pane1;
. . .
GraphScene scene = new DemoGraphScene();
. . .
SwingNode swingScene = new SwingNode();
swingScene.setContent(scene.getView());
. . .
pane1.getChildren().add(swingScene);
```

**Notes of Confusion**

It is especially confusing because the visual library works with a scene and the JavaFX library also works with a scene, but they are different scenes from different libraries, so you need to wrap the Visual Library scene view in a JavaFX node in order to display it in a JavaFX scene.

Additionally, when mixing Swing and JavaFX code, ensure you execute Swing code on the Swing event dispatch thread and JavaFX code on the JavaFX application thread - otherwise things could go badly wrong.

I'm not a big fan of mixing Swing and JavaFX, usually I recommend that if you want to use Swing, then write a 100% Swing App and if you want to use JavaFX, write a 100% JavaFX App.

**Executable Sample**

Here is an executable sample.  The sample relies on the source code at: https://platform.netbeans.org/graph/examples.html.  To use it, download the sample project from that link, paste the sample code below into the 
NetBeans project and right-click to run it.

[image: graph]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import org.netbeans.api.visual.graph.GraphScene;
import org.netbeans.api.visual.widget.Widget;

public class FXGraphDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
        createAndSetSwingContent(swingNode);

        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(swingNode), 400, 300);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private void createAndSetSwingContent(final SwingNode swingNode) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final GraphScene graphScene = new DemoGraphScene();

                String helloNodeID = "Hello";
                String worldNodeID = "World";
                String edge = "edge";

                Widget hello = graphScene.addNode (helloNodeID);
                Widget world = graphScene.addNode (worldNodeID);

                graphScene.addEdge (edge);

                graphScene.setEdgeSource(edge, helloNodeID);
                graphScene.setEdgeTarget(edge, worldNodeID);

                hello.setPreferredLocation (new Point (100, 100));
                world.setPreferredLocation (new Point (300, 200));

                final JComponent sceneView = graphScene.createView();

                final JScrollPane panel = new JScrollPane (sceneView);
                panel.getHorizontalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement (32);
                panel.getHorizontalScrollBar().setBlockIncrement (256);
                panel.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement (32);
                panel.getVerticalScrollBar().setBlockIncrement (256); 

                panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (400, 300));

                swingNode.setContent(panel);
            }
        });
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Caveat**

The sample (often, but not always) has a issue when it initially paints, it will flash black for a second and log a NullPointerExcepton when trying to calculate a Rectangle (for reasons unbeknownst to me - seems a bit like a race condition somewhere).  After that though, it seems to display and work OK.  To get around the black flash and NullPointerException, you can display the graph in a JFrame rather than a SwingNode, but then it shows in its own separate window rather than being embedded in a JavaFX scene.

Comment: I did this:

SwingNode swingScene = new SwingNode(); SwingNode swingScene1 = new SwingNode(); swingScene.setContent(new JButton("Click me!")); swingScene1.setContent(scene.getView()); pane1.getChildren().add(swingScene1);

When I do pane1.getChildren().add(swingScene1), I see nothing is displayed, but pane1.getChildren().add(swingScene) does show the button.

Comment: Thanks, the example works well, and like you said I have a null pointer exception, I also did not want to use Javafx and swing together, but I could not find any library for javafx that creates such graphs, have you come across any?

Comment: [yFiles for JavaFX](https://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfilesjavafx_about.html) (note yFiles is a commercial library, so you would have to contact the distributor yFiles for licensing information - if you want to use the library and it is suitable for your application).

Answer (score -3):

NetBeans Visual Library JavaFX port 
https://github.com/theanuradha/visual-library-fx/releases

https://github.com/theanuradha/visual-library-fx/tree/master/org-netbeans-api-visualfx/src/test/java/javaone/demo4

```
DemoGraphScene scene = new DemoGraphScene();

    String helloNodeID = "Hello";
    String worldNodeID = "World";
    String edge = "edge";

    Widget hello = scene.addNode(helloNodeID);
    Widget world = scene.addNode(worldNodeID);

    scene.addEdge(edge);

    scene.setEdgeSource(edge, helloNodeID);
    scene.setEdgeTarget(edge, worldNodeID);

    hello.setPreferredLocation(new Point(0, 0));
    world.setPreferredLocation(new Point(400, 200));

    final SceneNode sceneView =  scene.createView();
```

[image]